# Linux remote tool-winexe username/password

Tags: linux, windows, message, winexe, remotecommand

I am using winexe to send remote commands from my Ubuntu computer to Windows computer. Works great IF i user domain/username%password . However I believe in psExec which is a utility to send remote commands from windows to windows, does not need a username password combo.

So this command works:

```
bin/winexe -U user%password //computer 'msg  hello world'
```

this one doesn't

`bin/winexe //computer 'msg hello world'` No error just list commands in winexe

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

seems there is no way to avoid to input username/password, but you can try below way:

```
winexe --authentication-file //computer 'msg  hello world'
```

Create the authentication file in this format.

```
domain=domainName
username=myUserName
password=myPassword
```